# css transition effect not working on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply CSS3 transition effect on a form expansion when its heading is clicked but it isn't working

**HTML:**

```
<section class="widget" id="widget-1">
    <h4>Contact Us</h4>
    <form class="contact-form collapse" role="form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Question"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</section><!-- widget-1 -->
```

**CSS**

```
#widget-1 h4{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#widget-1 form.collapse{
    height: 0px;
}
#widget-1 .contact-form{
    overflow: hidden;
    height:auto;
    transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.9s linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.9s linear;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#widget-1 h4').click(function(){
        $('.contact-form').toggleClass('collapse');
    });
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jevon/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

Comment: always include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Just saying, What about the jQuery slideToggle() animation?! http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS transition height: 0; to height: auto;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3YQc7/)**</kbd>

js

```
$('#widget-1 h4').click(function () {
    if ($('#widget-1 form').is(":hidden")) {
        $('.contact-form').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $('#widget-1 form').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

css

```
#widget-1 h4 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#widget-1 form {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Transitioning over `height: auto` will not work. A workaround is to transition `max-height` from `0` to something that will never be an actual boundary of the box, as per this answer:
[How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto)

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like below:

```
#widget-1 .contact-form{
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100px; //Change this
    transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.9s linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.9s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to change your css to

```
#widget-1 form.collapse{
    display: none;  
}
```

and do the transition with jQuery:

```
$('#widget-1 h4').click(function(){
    $('.contact-form').toggle(900);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition will never run, because the `.contact-form` class is always applied to the element and the state never changes.
You're using jQuery, so you can use its `.slideToggle()` function and get rid of the CSS transition, like this: http://jsbin.com/papudizi/2/edit

```
$('#widget-1 h4').click(function(){
    $('.contact-form').slideToggle();
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want a pure-CSS solution, you can do it on `:hover` instead of on click. In this case, apply the `transition` to the `.contact-form` class and the height in a new `#widget-1:hover .contact-form` rule, so it will be applied to the .contact-form element when the cursor is over the #widget-1 element.

```
#widget-1 .contact-form{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.9s linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.9s linear;
}
#widget-1:hover .contact-form{
    height: 100px;
}
```

See it here: http://jsbin.com/talelufu/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Change the height defining a value, like so:

```
#widget-1 .contact-form{
    overflow: hidden;
    height:200px; /* Here we go */
    transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.9s linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.9s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.9s linear;
}
```